# Pointer to subarray defined by a map

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

I want to define a pointer to a subarray. For a simple range this is easily done by `pointer => array(i:j)`, but I can't figure out how to do this for a map like `k=[k1,k2,k3]`. If I would define another array I could use a loop like `array2=[(array1(k(j)),j=1,size(k,1))]`. But it isn't possible to assign a pointer in a similar way (`pointer => [(array1(k(j)),j=1,size(k,1))]`) since the r.h.s. of the expression seems to define another variabel which then not even has the target attribute. For simple tasks, a trick around this, is to first assign a pointer to the total array an to use the map on the readout. But in my case this doesn't seem to be possible.

I will attach to examples: The first one shows what I described above. The second one is a more complicated example, where the trick doesn't work anymore. And in addition a two dimensional map is required.

Minimal example:

```
program test

integer, parameter :: n=10,n_k=3
real,target :: a(1:n)
real :: b(1:n_k)
integer :: k(1:n_k)
integer :: j
real,pointer :: p(:)

! fill array a and define map k:
a=[(real(j),j=1,n)]
k=[((j+1)*2,j=1,n_k)]

! can be used to print the arrays:
!write(*,*) a
!write(*,*) k
! can be used to write only the part of a defined by k:
!write(*,*) (a(k(j)),j=1,n_k)

! this an similar things didn't work:
!p(1:n_k) => [(a(k(j)),j=1,n_k)]

! works, but not generally:
p => a
write(*,*) (p(k(j)),j=1,n_k)

! works, only for arrays:
b=(/(a(k(j)),j=1,n_k)/)
write(*,*) b

end program
```

More complicated (but also kind of minimal) example which shows (hopefully) the problem I really have. For an easy understanding some explanation leads through it. There are plenty of write commands to print the arrays. I appreciate for the amount of code, but I really don't see how to make a shorter and understandable working example:

```
module mod1

type base
   real :: a
end type

type,extends(base) ::  type1
end type

type,extends(base) :: type2
   type(type1),allocatable :: b(:)
end type

type(type2),allocatable,target :: c(:)

contains

subroutine printer(z)
   class(*),pointer,dimension(:) :: z
   integer :: j,a_z,n_z
   character(len=40) :: f,ff='(F10.2,1x))',form_z

   ! define format for printing:
   a_z=lbound(z,1)
   n_z=ubound(z,1)
   write(f,'(I0)') (n_z-a_z+1)
   form_z="("//trim(adjustl(f))//ff

   ! writing:
   select type(z)
   class is (base)
      write(*,form_z) (z(j)%a,j=a_z,n_z)
   end select
end subroutine

end module

program test

use mod1

integer,parameter :: n_b=8,n_c=6,n_js=3,n_ls=2
integer :: js(1:n_js),ls(1:n_ls)
integer :: j,l
class(*),pointer :: p(:)
character(len=40) :: f,ff='(F10.2,1x))',form_c,form_b

! define format for printing:
write(f,'(I0)') n_b
form_b="("//trim(adjustl(f))//ff
write(f,'(I0)') n_c
form_c="("//trim(adjustl(f))//ff

! creating and filling the arrays:
allocate(c(n_c))
c%a=[(2d0*real(j),j=1,n_c)]
do j=1,n_c
   allocate(c(j)%b(n_b))
   c(j)%b%a=[(real(l)*1d1**(j-1),l=1,n_b)]
end do

! write arrays to compare later:
write(*,form_c) c%a
write(*,*)
write(*,form_b) (c(j)%b%a,j=1,n_c)
write(*,*)

! denfining two maps (size and entries will be input in the final program):
js=[1,4,6]
ls=[2,7]

! using the maps to print only the desired entries:
write(*,*) (c(js(j))%a,j=1,n_js)
write(*,*)
write(*,*) ((c(js(j))%b(ls(l))%a,j=1,n_js),l=1,n_ls)
write(*,*)

! !!! here I want to use the maps as well, but so far I only know how to use ranges:
p => c(1:4)
call printer(p)
write(*,*)
p => c(2)%b(3:6)
call printer(p)
write(*,*)

end program
```

Edit:
Just for the record, I solved the problem now by using arrays of derived types including pointers and slightly changing the calling subroutines.

Comment: you can associate a pointer by adding a stride as well, e.g. `p=>a(4:8:2)`, then `p` will point to section `4` till `8` of array `a` with a stride of `2`. Of course, then your map has to be regularly strided.

Comment: The map is arbitrary and defined on input.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with pointer association (e.g. `pointer1 => array1(vector_subscript)`.  Section 7.2.2.2 of the Fortran 2008 standard that disallows this is:

> R733 *pointer-assignment-stmt* **is** *data-pointer-object* [ (*bounds-spec-list*) ] => *data-target*

There are two other forms, but they do not match your use, nor would they change the outcome.  Reading further:

> R737 *data-target* **is** *variable*
>   C724 (R737) A *variable* shall have either the TARGET or POINTER attribute, and shall not be an array section with a vector subscript.

This is why you cannot perform the pointer association your are attempting.  You can however work around this and with pointer allocation.  See this code:

```
n_k = 3
k = [((j+1)*2,j=1,n_k)] ! a vector subscript
p => a(k)               ! NOT OK. Violates C724
allocate(p(n_k))        ! Associate your pointer this way
p = a(k)                ! This is OK. 
write(*,*) p
```

Which yields (wrapped in your example program):

```
% ./ptrtest                      
   4.00000000       6.00000000       8.00000000
```

This allocates `p` to be the proper size and then assigns from `a` with a vector subscript.  This gets around the issue of directly associating `p` with a map of `a`.   This snippet assumes the variables are declared and initialized per your example code.  This shows that you can assign a vector subscript of an array to a pointer, but only one that is already associated, not during the association.

---

As noted in a comment to your Q, if you have a regular stride, you can make the pointer association directly.  For your first test case, this would be equivalent and work:

```
p => a(4:2:8)            ! Allocation to a strided array is allowed
```

If however, you have an irregular vector subscript then the method in this answer will be what you need to use to accomplish the pointer association.

---

Another workaround you can use is passing a pointer and the map to a procedure.  Consider the following code:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: nx = 10, nx_m = 3
  integer,dimension(nx_m) :: x_map
  integer :: i
  real, dimension(nx),target :: a
  real, dimension(:), pointer :: p

! initialize array
  a = [(real(i*2),i=1,10)]
  write (*,'(10(f5.1 x))') a

!define a map
  x_map = [1, 9, 4]

! associate pointer
  p => a

  call print_map(p, x_map)

contains

subroutine print_map(apointer, map)
  implicit none
  real, dimension(:), pointer :: apointer
  integer, dimension(:) :: map

  write (*,*) apointer(map)

   end subroutine print_map
end program test
```

In this case, `p` "knows" about `a` and the map of elements in `a` can be calculated in the caller.  Rather than associating (`=>`) `p` as a map of `a` (which cannot be done), `p` is associated to `a` and the map passed along with it.

This code produces the output:

```
% ./ptrtest3                       
2.0   4.0   6.0   8.0  10.0  12.0  14.0  16.0  18.0  20.0
2.00000000       18.0000000       8.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But than `p` is just a regular array and not a pointer, and thus doesn't "know" about it's target.

Comment: @PeMa that is true.  Unless you have an even stride and do `p => a(1:2:10)` you won't be able to accomplish what you want with an arbitrary map.

Comment: +1, but for the second part of the answer (didn't get what the first has to do with it though). For an arbitrary map, just use an array of indices like you're already doing, and you can then either pass that along with the data for printing, or create a copy like in this answer (although I would recommend no to use a pointer).

Comment: @steabert the first part is just justifying why he cant use a map to assign arbitrary elements of an array to a pointer.  I like to include the relevant bits of the standard rather just saying "you can't do this because its not in the standard".

Comment: @casey: it seems I just needed to reread the first part of the question. The OP says you can't do `array2=[(array1(k(j)),j=1,size(k,1))]` with a pointer, but that's not correct, you can perfectly do that as long as the pointer is associated. But now I understand that he meant you can't do `array2=>...` which is what you understood his question as. So, in my view, the answer was strange, as it confirmed what he was claiming. The first sentence in your answer should be: you can't do `array2=>...`, because the 'this' in my view seemed to refer to to `array2=...`. I hope that makes sense? :)

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. Still this answer is was what I knew already. I don't even see why `p` should have the pointer attribut in this work around.

Comment: @PeMa see my most recent edit for another workaround that might work better for you.