# Fortran pointer to arbitrary elements of an array

Tags: pointers, fortran

I would like to create a pointer array (ptr) in Fortran to the non-zero elements of a larger array.

I can point to individual elements in a do loop like this:

```
integer, pointer :: ptr1
integer, target :: iarray
 do i = 1, SIZE(iarray)
   if(iarray(i) > 0)
     ptr => iarray(i)
   end if
 end do
```

Can I create a pointer which points to *all* of the non-zero elements at once?

Comment: Do you want the pointer to be an array (pointing to non-zero elements of `iarray` all at the same time) instead of looping as a scalar individually (as it is in the fragment at the moment)?  [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24310495/3157076) shows that you can't have an arbitrary subset as pointer target.

Comment: @francescalus - yes I want pointer to be an array pointing to non-zero element.

Comment: @Mark - I'm actually trying to change a sparse matrix A (that depends on iarray..wherever iarray is zero, A is also zero) to a non-sparse matrix in order to save memory (as I'm running out of it). In order to create a mapping I'm trying to get the pointer array.

Comment: In which case you cannot do this, for reasons explained in answer to the linked question. However, you can use parse storage structures as a _copy_ (replacement) instead of using pointers. (Pointing to "elements 5, 9, 27, ..." or something general like that would be to an attempt to use a vector subscript.)

Comment: I think there was a little bit of confusion caused by the way you used "sparse" in the question. Some people automatically think that a "sparse array" is a way of referencing just the non-zero elements of a (mathematical) sparse matrix, and a "dense array" as being the unpacked matrix even if there are lots of zero elements in there. I've tried to edit the question to avoid this confusion (and correct your example code) and add your requirements from the comments. If you think I haven't expressed what you mean, then please feel free to "roll back" my edit.

Comment: You can instead make 1D-array of all non-zero entries, and two 1D integer arrays of their indices. That's an easy way to create a sparse representation if much more than 2/3 of the values are 0.